# Passing vue function data into modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

I have a modal and vue function that is successully opening a modal when a button is clicked (you can see this is happening by setting showModal to true in the function)

My issue: I have two variables `asset, eventObj` in the function that are logging in the console but I don;t know how to pass the value from there into the modal. The click event and modal all work, I just need to know how to pass the clicked item's variables into the modal as values

```
    <script type="text/x-template" id="modal-template">
    <transition name="modal">
    <div class="modal-mask">
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-container">

          <div class="modal-header">
            <slot name="header">
              default header
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <slot name="body">
              default body
            </slot>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <slot name="footer">
              default footer
              <button class="modal-default-button" @click="$emit('close')">
                OK
              </button>
            </slot>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </transition>
    </script>

    <modal v-if="showModal" @close="showModal = false">
    <!--
    you can use custom content here to overwrite
    default content
    -->
    <h3 slot="header">custom header</h3>
    </modal>



    Vue.component('modal', {
      template: '#modal-template'
    })

    export default {
        data () {
            return {
                events: [

                ],
                showModal: false        }
        },
        methods: {

          eventClick: function(e) {
          var eventObj = e.event;
          var asset = e.event.extendedProps.asset;
          this.showModal = true;
          console.log(asset);

        },
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want to do, but I think your goal is to pass parameters from the parent into the modal as you open it. I think the best way to do so is storing the objects in a variable and giving them tho the modal component as properties. The Syntax is this:

In the modal component itself:

```
props: {
    eventObj: Object,
    asset: Object
}
```

In the parent component, you need to declare the variables in data (with null or empty values) and set the values in the eventClick-function before you open the modal by switching the flag.

```
data() {
   return {
      events: [...],
      showModal: false,
      eventObj: {},
      asset: {}
   }
}
methods: {
   eventClick: function(e) {
      this.eventObj = e.event;
      this.asset = e.event.extendedProps.asset;
      this.showModal = true;
   }
}
```

In the template-part of the parent component:

```
<modal 
    v-if="showModal" 
    v-bind:eventObj="eventObj" 
    v-bind:asset="asset" 
    @close="showModal = false">
      <!-- your stuff... --!>
</modal>
```

Comment: Ok so if I want to show the asset in the modal it would be {asset} ?

Comment: If it is a string, yes, but with two mustaches, like {{asset}}. In this case you also have to set the Datatypes from Object to String in the props-declaration and data-declaration